# How do I check if command failed... with a pipe?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, error-handling, pipe

So I have a script like this:

```sh
somecommad | grep --invert-match something
```

I'd like to be able to conditionally run a different command if `somecommand` fails. Here's what I tried:

```sh
somecommand | grep --invert-match something || {
    echo 'Oops'
}
```

But that didn't work (the `grep` wasn't executed). What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you can use bash's `PIPESTATUS` array: see for example [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14276/65304)

Comment: When you use a pipe, `grep` starts *before* you can necessarily know if `somecommand` has failed or not. Do you want to the other command's output to go to `grep` as well? `{ somecommand || { echo Oops; }; } | grep ...`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@steeldriver [mentioned in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370604/how-do-i-check-if-command-failed-with-a-pipe#comment2356512_1370604) that `PIPESTATUS` might work. I tried it, and it worked well. Here's what I did:

```sh
somecommand | grep --invert-match something
if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" != "0" ]; then
    echo 'Oops'
fi
```

It runs the command as before, but then I have an `if` statement to look at the `PIPESTATUS` array. I only care about the first element, so that is the one I look at. I check it it failed (if the exit code is not `0`), and it it did fail, run `echo 'Oops'`

Comment: Does this work regardless of `set -o pipefail`?

Comment: @PedroA I don't know what that does. If you try it, feel free to edit my answer or post your own, though.

Comment: Yes it works with pipefail, but not with `set -e -o pipefail` as it won’t reach the if.

Comment: I tested and it worked for me regardless of the `pipefail` option's status. If you need to examine more than one status, or one status more than once, first assign them to a variable, e.g. `statuses=( ${PIPESTATUS[@]} )` because any subsequent command will overwrite the built-in variable.

Answer (score 10):

Another way, depending on the exact behaviour needed, is to use [the `pipefail` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines):

> The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command
> in the pipeline, unless the `pipefail` option is enabled (see [The Set
> Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)).
> If `pipefail` is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of
> the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero
> if all commands exit successfully.

So, if you don't care which of `somecommand` or `grep` failed, as long as one of those did fail:

```
set -o pipefail
if ! somecommand | grep --invert-match something; then
    echo 'Oops'
fi
```